# how to make dataset like this in tensorflow2: <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.string)>

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, translation

I want to make my own dataset when doing translation in NLP. For example,
x = ["It is an apple"]
y = ["It is a pear"].
How show I make a dataset which can fit "<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.string)>".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to create a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) with these two tensors as argument to the [`from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) static method.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = ["It is an apple"]
y = ["It is a pear"]

xy = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
print(xy)
>>> <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.string)>
```

This corresponds to the Dataset signature that you are looking for. You can create a prefetch dataset with [`prefetch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) method:

```py
dataset = xy.prefetch(1)
print(dataset)
>>> <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.string)>
```